# how do i fetch_* rows after calling mysqli_stmt_store_result?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE dataStr = ? LIMIT 20");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $search);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
echo "rows are " . $stmt->num_rows;

$rs = $stmt->get_result();
while($r = $rs->fetch_object()) print_r($r);

?>
```

When I call `$stmt->store_result()` to let `$stmt->num_rows` work, the subsequent call of `$stmt->get_result()` returns FALSE. If I comment the `store_result()` row, everything works fine (except of course num_rows)

How can I access the `mysqli_result` class instance, and its `fetch_array()`, `fetch_assoc()`, `fetch_object()` methods after I called `$stmt->store_result()` ?

Comment: apparently seems the only way to use the resultset after `store_result()` is using `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`, `mysqli_stmt_fetch` with the help of `mysqli_stmt_result_metadata`. basically I have to reimplement the `mysqli_result` class myself :|

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE dataStr = ? LIMIT 20");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $search);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();
        echo "rows are " . $stmt->num_rows;

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {

            echo 'ID: '.$row['id'].'<br>';

        }

        $stmt->free_result();


    ?>
```